# Clojure http-kit: CORS set up not working

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

My simple http-kit server:

```
(ns figgy.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [org.httpkit.server :as server]
            [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [ring.middleware.cors :refer [wrap-cors]]
            [compojure.route :as route]))
(defn fps-handler [req]
  {:status  200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body    "Pew pew!"})

(defn mail-man []
   "{\"Spongebob Narrator\": \"5 years later...\"}")

(defn mail-handler [req]
  {:status  200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/json"} ;(1)
   :body    (mail-man)}) ;(2)

(defn general-handler [req]
  {:status  200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body    "All hail General Zod!"})

(defroutes app-routes ;(3)
  (GET "/" [] fps-handler)
  (POST "/postoffice" [] mail-handler)
  (ANY "/anything-goes" [] general-handler)
  (route/not-found "You Must Be New Here")) ;(4)

(def app
  (-> app-routes
    (wrap-cors
     :access-control-allow-origin [#".*"]
     :access-control-allow-headers ["Content-Type"]
     :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post :delete :options])))

(defn -main
  "This is our app's entry point"
  [& args]
  (let [port (Integer/parseInt (or (System/getenv "PORT") "8080"))]
    (server/run-server #'app {:port port})
    (println (str "Running webserver at http:/127.0.0.1:" port "/"))))
```

Every time I make a call from my JS app I'm getting a CORS error despite setting up **wrap-cors**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:9500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example from our site including all the headers I needed to pass:

```
{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" origin
 "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true"
 "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Authentication, If-Match, If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-Unmodified-Since"}
```

I cut out the application specific ones. You may need to include more such as `X-My-Auth-Thing` in the headders section.

Comment: wrap-cors is actually working, the problem seems to be that when I include **:headers         {:authorization (basic-auth-header email password)}** in the client side code, the request to the backend fails.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may lie in your comment.

> wrap-cors is actually working, the problem seems to be that when I include :headers {:authorization (basic-auth-header email password)} in the client side code, the request to the backend fails. –

This would work. `:access-control-allow-headers ["Content-Type" "Authorization"]`.

By the way, I want to ask if your code in your question is the actual code in your application. If you use some kind of authentication middleware, you shoud add `wrap-cors` before the auth middleware. Browsers doesn't include "Authentication" header in preflight OPTIONS request automatically then requests fail. To make wrap-cors first may solve your problem.

Browser devtool will also help your debugging. You can see preflight requests and response in Network tab in Chrome devtool.